# django admin list_display - returning multiple column values with single callable (django 1.9, python=2.7.x)

Tags: python, django

So my Django code for `admin.py` looks something like this:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUseChangeForm
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin', 'is_superuser', 
                    'total_tasks', 'total_tests')
    list_filter = ('is_admin', 'is_superuser')
    ordering = ('email',)

    def total_tests(self, obj):
        others = OtherObject.objects.filter(user=obj)
        total = 0
        correct = 0
        for other in others:
            # ... etc
        return # ...
    total_tests.short_description = "Tests Taken"

    def total_tasks(self, obj):
        return OtherObject.objects.filter(user=obj).count()
    total_tasks.short_description = "Tasks Done"
```

However, realizing that every callable I make (`total_tasks`, `total_tests`) will make this page load suuuuuuper slow when I have more database entries - is there a way to share computation? Maybe cache so that every callable doesn't have to query ALL the items from different tables over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

First of all tune tune your code.

1. `total_tasks` - should be `OtherObject.objects.filter(user_id=obj.pk).count()` - it will boost you a bit.
2. You've hidden the body of for loop in `total_tests`. I am afraid that you refer to some objects connected with `OtherObject` model. Without [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) you can almost DDOS your database and make the view extremaly slow.

Comment: Changing the queryset to `user_id=obj.pk` will not change the SQL query.

Comment: Yes, but removes not necessary processing and object wrapping on the client side. That is why i wrote "a bit" :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'not necessary processing and object wrapping on the client side'.

Answer (score 1):

Override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method for your [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch the related objects. You can then modify your methods to use the prefetched `self.otherobject_set.all()` instead of querying `OtherObject.objects.filter(user=obj)` once for each method for each row in the queryset.

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('otherobject')
        return qs

    def total_tests(self, obj):
        others = self.otherobject_set.all()
        ...

    def total_tasks(self, obj):
        return len(self.otherobject_set.all())
```