# ManyToMany Relationships. Returning fields in def __str__ method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, many-to-many

I have two models:

`AffectedSegment` model

```
class AffectedSegment(models.Model):

    SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA = 'Escápula'
    SEGMENTO_HOMBRO = 'Hombro'
    SEGMENTO_CODO = 'Codo'
    SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO = 'Antebrazo'
    SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA = 'Carpo/Muñeca'
    SEGMENTO_MANO = 'Mano'
    SEGMENT_CHOICES = (
        (SEGMENTO_ESCAPULA, u'Escápula'),
        (SEGMENTO_HOMBRO, u'Hombro'),
        (SEGMENTO_CODO, u'Codo'),
        (SEGMENTO_ANTEBRAZO, u'Antebrazo'),
        (SEGMENTO_CARPO_MUNECA, u'Carpo/Muñeca'),
        (SEGMENTO_MANO, u'Mano'),
    )

    affected_segment = models.CharField(
        max_length=12,
        choices=SEGMENT_CHOICES,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Segmento afectado',
        help_text='Ingrese uno o mas segmentos corporal de miembros superiores'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Segmentos corporales'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.affected_segment
```

And `Movement` model. Please review the `__str__` method of this model at the end:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Tipo de movimiento'
    )

    corporal_segment_associated = models.ManyToManyField(
        AffectedSegment,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Segmento corporal asociado')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Movimiento'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{}".format(self.type, self.corporal_segment_associated)
```

I have another model named `RehabilitationSession` in which I want allow the possibility of choose multiple affected_segments and multiple movements such as follow:

class RehabilitationSession(models.Model):

```
affected_segment = models.ManyToManyField(
    AffectedSegment,
    verbose_name='Segmento afectado',
    #related_name='affectedsegment'
)
movement = models.ManyToManyField(
    Movement,  # Modelo encadenado
    verbose_name='Movimiento',
    #related_name = 'movement'
)
```

In my Django Admin when I go to the `RehabilitationSession` model I see the following in the `movement` field:

[image]

I understand that in the `ManyToMany` relationships, a intermediate table is created with the ID's fields of the two tables which make the `m2m` relationship of this way:

[image]

My question is:

How to can I make that in my `Movement` model I can access to the `corporal_segment_associated` field that I want call in the `__str__` method?

Any orientation is very useful
:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `self.corporal_segment_associated` is not a list of the related items, it is a `ManyRelatedManager`. When you call `str(self.corporal_segment_associated)`, it returns the `AffectedSegment.None` string which you see in your screenshots.

To fetch the related segements, you can do `self.corporal_segment_associated.all()`. This will return a queryset of the related objects. You then have to convert this queryset to a string before you use it in the `__str__` method. For example, you could do:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        corporal_segment_associated = ", ".join(str(seg) for seg in self.corporal_segment_associated.all())
        return "{},{}".format(self.type, corporal_segment_associated)
```

It might not be a good idea to access `self.corporal_segment_associated.all()` in the `__str__` method. It means that Django will do extra SQL queries for every item in the drop down list. You might find that this causes poor performance.

Comment: thanks for the response. And it's true when you tell me about of the extra SQL queries for every item. There is some way of measure this performance in one situatios such as this.. ?

Comment: I didn't have a specific tool in mind to measure performance. If the page loads quick enough for you, then I wouldn't worry about it too much. If it is slow, then you could use `prefetch_related` to speed it up (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698396/113962)). If that's still too slow, you'll need to think about a different approach. The django-debug-toolbar can be useful to view the SQL queries for a page.