# Django model be related to objects of different types

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a model called `Assignment`. Each Assignment can hold multiple questions of different types. That is, an Assignment can have Multiple Choice Questions, Essay Questions, True or False Questions.

Each of the question types have their own model. Of course, they are related to the assignment by `ForeignKey`.

How can I related them to the assignment such that to get all the questions (of different types) all I have to do is, for example, call:

`assignment1.questions.all()`

I have seen a few write-ups on things like GenericForeignKey, ContentType, etc. but I am yet to make them work.

Like this:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    # ...assignment fields

class MultipleChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)


class TrueOrFalseQuestion(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)

class EssayQuestion(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment)
```

So, I can get all the questions for the assignment instance by doing `assignment1.questions.all()`, for example, as mentioned above

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Also, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920941/traverse-multiple-foreign-keys-in-django-detailview ?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a ManyToMany relations with an explicit through field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields .

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
  m_question = models.ManyToMany("MultipleChoiceQuestion")
  tf_question = models.ManyToMany("TrueOrFalseQuestion")
  e_question = models.ManyToMany("EssayQuestion")
  [...]
  def __str__(self):
     all_m_questions = ", ".join(str(q) for q in self.m_question.all())
        return "{},{}".format(self.type, all_m_questions) #etc...


class MultipleChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
  name=...

class TrueOrFalseQuestion(models.Model):
  name=...

class EssayQuestion(models.Model):
  name=...
```

? This way you can access the different kinds of question of a specific assignment. (see also [ManyToMany Relationships. Returning fields in def __str__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729238/manytomany-relationships-returning-fields-in-def-str-method))

Another solution/integration to this solution is using a `through_field` as I mentioned in my comment. It depends on want to achieve and the scenario you're in.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I need to get each question type individually. I want to be able to do a `assignment1,questions.all()` and get all questions related to that assignment at once as a single queryset list

Comment: See the updated answer (not tested). Does it help? You'll have the list of questions when calling the assignment object.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Thanks for trying, nonetheless

Comment: I figured that I would just create a single `Question` model and give them types (like a choice field). It's better that way to reduce complexity